# Vue passing props via router-link with dynamic routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following route:

**routes/index.ts**

```
{
  path: "/flower/:id",
  name: "SingleFlower",
  component: () => import("@/components/SingleFlower/SingleFlower.vue"),
  meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  props: true 
},
```

and components:

**FlowersPage.vue**

```
...
<router-link
  v-for="flower in flowersArray"
  :key="flower.id"
  :to="{
    name: 'SingleFlower',
    params: { 
      id: flower.id,
    }, 
    //  I want to pass the rest of the props here, eg. flower.name and flower.desc 
  }"
>
  <FlowerCard :flower="flower" />
</router-link>
...
```

**SingleFlower.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="flower-container">
    {{ flower.id }} 
    {{ flower.name }} //  Using passed props here
    {{ flower.description }} //  Using passed props here
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  //  How to get props here from router-link and use them in the template
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "./FlowerPage.scss";
</style>
```

How I can achieve the desired effect, as described by the comments in the code above? I've tried to use params as props (e.g. params: { id: flower.id, name: flower.name, desc: flower.desc}) but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

a route with `props: true` will automatically assign route params to a component's props.  You can access the props as you would normally:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ flower.id }} {{ flower.name }} {{ flower.description }}</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
const flower = defineProps(['id', 'name', 'description']);
</script>
```

The only additional thing you need to do is make sure all the params are part of your URL.  If the param isn't in the URL, it won't be included as a param and it won't be assigned to a prop:

```js
{
  path: "/flower/:id/:name/:description",
  name: "SingleFlower",
  component: () => import("@/components/SingleFlower/SingleFlower.vue"),
  meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  props: true 
},
```

If a URL like that is not desirable, I would suggest combining vue-router with a state management library like Pinia.  Store your flower data in your Pinia store, then navigate using just `:id`, and finally load flower data by id when the new view is created/mounted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to have the same behavior, but without including params in the URL and using the store? If not, I will simply fetch the data for a specific flower directly in the component using the id.